# How to get specific data in a column by only using data from one cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I've a lot of sales orders, I've to fill out with a lot of data from different excel workbooks and worksheets. So I need an macro which can do it for me. I have 4 different Excel workbooks. 1 where the data have to be inserted and 3 where I have to get the data from. All the Excel workbooks have the sales orders listed,

So the macro has to scan for each Sales order in each workbook and then get specific data from the workbooks.

[image]

This is an example of the workbook where I paste the data.

[image]

Here's an example for a workbook where I have to copy the data.

So it has to copy:

[image]

And then paste it into the workbook where I have to paste the data.

If anyone could either give me a somewhere to begin or some piece of code, I would be more than happy!

Comment: What data are you taking from each workbook? E.G in some do you take multiple column data?

Comment: And also does Sales Order appear in every sheet and if yes, column A?

Comment: Are you sure you need a macro for this? Series of vlookups() could also do the trick and no macro writing experience would be required.

Comment: 1) Sales Order appears in all the workbooks/worksheets and yes, they are all in column A. 2) If I for example have Sales order "1111", I need specific data in the same column as the sales order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED SOLUTION BELOW. Not the prettiest code and there's probably a better way to do it, but it should do what you want it to in a roundabout way.

Copy this macro into a module in your master book that you're copying ***TO*** and save it somewhere as an XLSM file.

Place all 3 of your sheets (or as many as you want) that you want to copy ***FROM*** within a different folder somewhere and then insert that file location where noted in the macro.

This should loop through every file in the specified location, grab all used cells except the header row and paste them into the next available rows in Sheet2 on your master book.

Then the macro will run a vlookup on the copied over data against the sales order numbers and paste special to turn them back to values. Finally it will clear Sheet2 ready for next time you run it.

Obviously, if your sheets are named something else you can amend, or refer to them by number, but it should give you a starting point at least.

```
Sub CopyTheData()

Dim Folder As String
Dim File As Variant
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim This As Worksheet, That As Worksheet

Folder = "[FOLDER LOCATION HERE]"
File = Dir(Folder & "*.*")
Set This = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set That = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

While (File <> "")
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Folder & File)


    With wbk
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
        Selection.Copy Destination:=That.Range("B65536").End(xlUp)(2).Offset(0, -1)
    End With

    wbk.Close

    File = Dir
Wend

    This.Activate
    This.Range("B2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$A:$H,2,FALSE)"
    This.Range("C2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A:$H,4,FALSE)"
    This.Range("D2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A:$H,6,FALSE)"
    This.Range("E2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 4)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A:$H,8,FALSE)"

    With This.Range("B2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 4))
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With

    Columns("D:E").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

    That.Cells.ClearContents


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The date shows up as some random numbers like "42036", "42038" and like that, instead of the date. Do you know why? :)

Comment: They're formatting as General or Text format. Excel stores dates internally as sequential numbers beginning at 1st January 1900. 42036 for example is Excel's version of 1st February 2015. Simply add a line of code at the end `Columns("D:E").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"` to format those columns as dates. I've updated my answer to include that line.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Harley's code looks good, if you only want certain sheets to be used though you could paste the following in each of the sheets you want adding to the master sheet.

```
Dim owb As Workbook
Dim Master As Worksheet 
Dim Slave As Worksheet 'the following declares both master and slave as worksheets

fpath = "location of master workbook" 


Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath) 'opens the file path

Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("name of sheet in workbook your pasting from") 'declares this workbook and sheet as "master"
Set Slave = owb.Worksheets("name of sheet in master you are pasting to") 'declares the workbook and sheet you're copying to as "slave"


For j = 1 To 10000 '(the master sheet) 'goes through each row from 1 to 10000

For i = 1 To 10000 '(the slave sheet) 'again does the same and the slave sheet
If Trim(Master.Cells(j, 4).Value2) = vbNullString Then Exit For 'if the ID is blank it will exit and move on to the next row
If Master.Cells(j, 1).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 1).Value Then 'the 1 represents column A, if cell in column A matches the cell in column D in the masterwork book then it will..

        Slave.Cells(i, 2).Value = Master.Cells(j, 2).Value 
        'the cell here represent column B as it's a 2, you can change and add as many as you like to bring through the column


End If
Next


Next


MsgBox ("Successful")
```